# Need to modify text resizer plugin for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've installed a great and very simple text resizer plugin on a website that I'm working on, but I want to prevent the resizer from appearing on the front page. Unfortunately my knowledge of PHP is extremely limited so I'm not sure what the simplest way to do this might be.

Here is the code for the plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Post size text changer
Plugin URI: http://www.sooource.net/post-text-size-changer
Description: This plugin allows your blog to change the font size of entries 'on the fly'.
Version: 1.0
Author: TrueFalse
Author URI: http://www.sooource.net
License: GPLv2 or later
Text Domain: ptsc
Domain Path: /languages
*/

# Загрузка локализаций:
load_plugin_textdomain('ptsc', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/');

# Хуки, действия, фильтры:
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ptsc_enqueue_js');    // - подключение JavaScript к фронтенду.
add_action('admin_init', 'ptsc_options_fields');        // - регистрация полей в БД.
add_action('admin_menu', 'ptsc_admin_menu');            // - добавление пункта меню в админку.
add_filter('the_content', 'ptsc_insert_html');          // - вставка HTML-кода в пост.
register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, 'ptsc_deinstall');    // - крючок деинсталляции.

# Подключение JavaScript:
function ptsc_enqueue_js() {
  wp_enqueue_script('resize', plugins_url('js/resize.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
}

# Вставка ссылок плагина:
function ptsc_insert_html($content) {
  if (is_singular())
    return ptsc_default('ptsc_html_before').
    '<a id="increase-font" href="#">[ A+ ] </a>/<a id="decrease-font" href="#">[ A- ] </a>'.
    ptsc_default('ptsc_html_after'). '<div class="resize">'. $content. '</div>';
  else
    return $content;
}

# Регистрируем новую страницу на вкладке "Параметры".
function ptsc_admin_menu() {
  add_options_page(
    __('Post size text changer', 'ptsc'),
    __('Post size text changer', 'ptsc'),
    'manage_options',
    'post-size-text-changer.php',
    'ptsc_options_page');
}

# Показываем форму:
function ptsc_options_page() {
  echo '<div class="wrap">';
  screen_icon();
  echo '<h2>'. __('Post size text changer', 'ptsc'). '</h2>';
  echo '<form method="post" action="options.php">';
  do_settings_sections('ptsc_page');
  settings_fields('ptsc_fields');
  submit_button();
  echo '</form>';
  echo '</div>';
}

# Регистрируем поля в БД и оформляем их отображение.
function ptsc_options_fields() {
  register_setting('ptsc_fields', 'ptsc_html_before');
  register_setting('ptsc_fields', 'ptsc_html_after');
  add_settings_section('ptsc_section_id', NULL, 'ptsc_section_callback', 'ptsc_page');
  add_settings_field('ptsc_setting-html-before-id', __('Before links', 'ptsc'). ':', 'ptsc_html_before_field_callback', 'ptsc_page', 'ptsc_section_id');
  add_settings_field('ptsc_setting-html-after-id', __('After links', 'ptsc'). ':', 'ptsc_html_after_field_callback', 'ptsc_page', 'ptsc_section_id');
}

# Функции вывода элементов формы на экран:
function ptsc_section_callback() {
  echo '<p>'. __('Please configure HTML-wrapper to change the style of inserting the plugin', 'ptsc'). '.</p>';
}
function ptsc_html_before_field_callback() {
  echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" value="'. esc_html(stripslashes(ptsc_default('ptsc_html_before'))). '" id="ptsc-html-before-field" name="ptsc_html_before" />';
}
function ptsc_html_after_field_callback() {
  echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" value="'. esc_html(stripslashes(ptsc_default('ptsc_html_after'))). '" id="ptsc-html-after-field" name="ptsc_html_after" />';
}

# Считывание полей из БД и установка значений по умолчанию:
function ptsc_default($field) {
  $default = get_option($field);
  if ($field == 'ptsc_html_before')
    $default = ( !empty($default) ) ? $default: '<p style="text-align:right">';
  elseif ($field == 'ptsc_html_after')
    $default = ( !empty($default) ) ? $default: '</p>';
  return $default;
}

# Хук деисталляции:
function ptsc_deinstall() {
  delete_option('ptsc_html_before');
  delete_option('ptsc_html_after');
}

?>
```

I assume that a simple if/else loop would be the way to go, particularly as WP has an `is_home()` function, but I don't read Russian, and I'm not sure where to begin. Any thoughts? Or might there be an even easier way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
function ptsc_insert_html($content) {
  if (is_singular() && !is_front_page())
    return ptsc_default('ptsc_html_before').
    '<a id="increase-font" href="#">[ A+ ] </a>/<a id="decrease-font" href="#">[ A- ] </a>'.
    ptsc_default('ptsc_html_after'). '<div class="resize">'. $content. '</div>';
  else
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: In fact I was able to easily switch out the ugly text `[ A+ ]` and `[ A- ]` things for actual buttons. Very easy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't read Russian but I did throw some of text into Google Translate. The comments didn't seem to help that much.

Anyway, this block here: (english comment translation : Insert links plugin:)

```
# Вставка ссылок плагина:
function ptsc_insert_html($content) {
  if (is_singular())
    return ptsc_default('ptsc_html_before').
    '<a id="increase-font" href="#">[ A+ ] </a>/<a id="decrease-font" href="#">[ A- ] </a>'.
    ptsc_default('ptsc_html_after'). '<div class="resize">'. $content. '</div>';
  else
    return $content;
}
```

looks like it is taking your post/page content then wrapping it with a resize class. As well it looks like it is inserting the links to make the text larger/smaller.

I would change it to make resize a variable that only has the string resize when home != true.

Untested but something like this:

```
function ptsc_insert_html($content) {

  $resize = '';
  if (!is_home()) {
     $resize = 'resize';
  }

  if (is_singular())
    return ptsc_default('ptsc_html_before').
    '<a id="increase-font" href="#">[ A+ ] </a>/<a id="decrease-font" href="#">[ A- ] </a>'.
    ptsc_default('ptsc_html_after'). '<div class="'. $resize .'">'. $content. '</div>';
  else
    return $content;
}
```

Hope that helps.